# How to check if the value of the span element is equal to another value using react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

i want to test if the value of span element is equal to another constant.

What i am trying to do?

I have a span element like below

```
render = () => {
    const compare_value = 5
    const span_value = 5
    return (
         <span data-test-id="test">{span_value}</span>
    );
}
```

Now within my test i do this

```
const span_element = getByTestId('test');
const value = span_element.innerHTML //this value is "5" a string

expect(value).toBe(compare_value);
```

Here in the expect statement i get error object.isequality

I get this error since value is string "5" and compare value is integer 5.

How can i fix this. could someone help me with this. I want to test if the value of spanelement is equal to the compare_value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast one of the values ( `value` or `compare_value`) to string.

```js
String(compare_value)
//or
compare_value.toString()
```